# Is it possible to set the dma buffer address for a network card?

Tags: windows, networking, dma

My understanding of network cards is that when receiving data, that data is DMA'd into main memory through the network card driver. The kernel then copies this memory into user space and sends any necessary messages.

My question is, in Windows, is it possible to set the address that the DMA is writing to? My goal is to eliminate the extra memory copy similar to the way NVidia's GPUDirect pipeline works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. I believe this is called "common buffer DMA". It is used for intelligent network adapters. Taking advantage of this would require writing your own network driver. Here is some microsoft documentation on it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx